# Cumulatively count values between range by group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum, running-count

Say I have the following data. For each user_id I want to get a cumulative count every time the difference score is <= -2 until it reaches a positive value. The count should then reset to zero and stay at that value until the next <= -2 is encountered for that user, where the count then starts again from 1 until the next positive value is reached. The result should be equivalent to what I have in cum_count.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                       'difference_score': [0.0, 1.0, -2.5, -2.5, -0.5, -1.5, 2.25, 2.25, -1.86, 0.0, -0.33, -1.33, -2.33, 0.0, 1.0, -2.67, -0.67, -0.67, 0.67, -0.33, -0.33, 1.0],
                       'cum_count': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

```
        user_id  difference_score  cum_count
0         1            0.0000          0
1         1            1.0000          0
2         1           -2.5000          1
3         1           -2.5000          2
4         1           -0.5000          3
5         1           -1.5000          4
6         1            2.2500          0
7         1            2.2500          0
8         2           -1.8571          0
9         2            0.0000          0
10        2           -0.3333          0
11        2           -1.3333          0
12        2           -2.3333          1
13        2            0.0000          0
14        3            1.0000          0
15        3           -2.6667          1
16        3           -0.6667          2
17        3           -0.6667          3
18        3            0.6667          0
19        3           -0.3333          0
20        3           -0.3333          0
21        3            1.0000          0
```

EDIT: Based on your solution mozway I have found a couple of instances where the proposed solution does not produce the intended results. My apologies, my example data was not extensive enough. I have now extended the above example data to highlight this.

For example, in the updated dataframe below, row 14 cum_count should be 0 as it is a new user and the difference score is > -2. However, cum_count2 produces a 1.

In addition, once a positive value is reached and the count resets to 0, the next time a value <= -2 is encountered for that user, the count should start again from 1. However, in row 19, cum_count2 continues counting from the previous count.

The updated cum_count column has the values I'm expected to be returned as compared to what the current solution is returning in cum_count2...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                       'difference_score': [0.0, 1.0, -2.5, -2.5, -0.5, -1.5, 2.25, 2.25, -1.86, 0.0, -0.33, -1.33, -2.33, -2.0, -1.0, -2.67, -0.67, -0.67, 0.67, -2.5, -0.33, 1.0],
                       'cum_count': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0]})
```

```
    user_id  difference_score  cum_count  cum_count2
0         1              0.00          0           0
1         1              1.00          0           0
2         1             -2.50          1           1
3         1             -2.50          2           2
4         1             -0.50          3           3
5         1             -1.50          4           4
6         1              2.25          0           0
7         1              2.25          0           0
8         2             -1.86          0           0
9         2              0.00          0           0
10        2             -0.33          0           0
11        2             -1.33          0           0
12        2             -2.33          1           1
13        2             -2.00          2           2
14        3             -1.00          0           1
15        3             -2.67          1           2
16        3             -0.67          2           3
17        3             -0.67          3           4
18        3              0.67          0           0
19        3             -2.50          1           5
20        3             -0.33          2           6
21        3              1.00          0           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use masks to define the start and stop, identify the consecutive matching values and use if to generate a group to perform a cumcount:

```
m1 = df['difference_score'].ge(0)
m2 = df['difference_score'].le(-2)
m3 = m2.groupby([df['user_id'], m1.cumsum()]).cummax()

group = (m3&~m3.groupby(df['user_id']).shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()

df['cum_count'] = df.groupby(['user_id', group]).cumcount().add(1).where(m3, 0)
```

output:

```
    user_id  difference_score  cum_count     m1     m2     m3  group
0         1              0.00          0   True  False  False      0
1         1              1.00          0   True  False  False      0
2         1             -2.50          1  False   True   True      1
3         1             -2.50          2  False   True   True      1
4         1             -0.50          3  False  False   True      1
5         1             -1.50          4  False  False   True      1
6         1              2.25          0   True  False  False      1
7         1              2.25          0   True  False  False      1
8         2             -1.86          0  False  False  False      1
9         2              0.00          0   True  False  False      1
10        2             -0.33          0  False  False  False      1
11        2             -1.33          0  False  False  False      1
12        2             -2.33          1  False   True   True      2
13        2             -2.00          2  False   True   True      2
14        3             -1.00          0  False  False  False      2
15        3             -2.67          1  False   True   True      3
16        3             -0.67          2  False  False   True      3
17        3             -0.67          3  False  False   True      3
18        3              0.67          0   True  False  False      3
19        3             -2.50          1  False   True   True      4
20        3             -0.33          2  False  False   True      4
21        3              1.00          0   True  False  False      4
```